# Trying to decipher this code which is encoded with HTML Special Characters

Tags: functions

I'm trying to get this code to work from this [site.](https://abhijitrawool.com/add-categories-and-tags-for-wordpress-pages/) The problem with it is that it has been copied and pasted form a non-php parsing browser I suspect. I've tried various ways to get the correct characters to work but it keeps crashing my local development site. Here's the code:

```
// Set any Custom Post Type to be displayed on the archive.php and tag.php
    function category_tag_archives( $wp_query ) {
     if ( $wp_query-&amp;gt;get( ‘category_name’ ) || $wp_query-
     &amp;gt;get( ‘cat’ ) || $wp_query-&amp;gt;get( ‘tag’ ) )
$wp_query-&amp;gt;set( ‘post_type’, ‘any’ );
}
add_action( ‘pre_get_posts’, ‘category_tag_archives’ );
```

The bit that I am trying to decipher is here:

```
$wp_query-&amp;gt;set
```

I've tried combinations of:

```
$wp_query-&>set
```

and

```
$wp_query=&>set
```

but no joy...

Thanks for all help with this!

(PS The purpose of this function is to allow archive to publish a loop of content from a WP Page rather than a WP Post)

Comment: This is not a question regarding WordPress development, but rather generic PHP syntax - as such it's off-topic for our site. Stackoverflow would be a more appropriate place to ask. But in short, it should be `$wp_query->set`. It's unclear why the source suggests that there should be an ampersand there. Google "PHP object operator".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code for you:

```
// Set any Custom Post Type to be displayed on the archive.php and tag.php

function category_tag_archives($wp_query) {
    if ($wp_query->get('category_name') || $wp_query->get('cat') || $wp_query->get('tag')) {
        $wp_query->set('post_type', 'any');
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'category_tag_archives');
```